# Weak Compact and separable sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is true the following statement?

Se $(X\|\cdot\|)$ a Banach espace, and $K\subset X$ a convex, weakly compact and separable set. Let $x_{n}$ a sequence in $K$. Thus, given any $\epsilon >0$ there is $x_{\epsilon}\in K$ and a subsequence of $x_{n}$ (noted in the some way such that:

$$
\lim_{n}\|x_{n}-x_{\epsilon}\|\leq \epsilon
$$

Can you help me????

Thanks!!

Comment: Take the closed unit ball in $\ell_2$, $(x_n)$ the sequence of the usual unit vectors in $\ell_2$, and $\epsilon=1/2$. $(x_n)$ does not possess a subsequence such as you desire.